# what is wrong with installing pycairo for igraph?

Tags: python, igraph, pycairo

I followed [the instructions here](http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/install.html) 
to install pycairo on win and be able to use plotting in igraph

I have python 2.7
pycairo 1.8.10

and dll files with the same numbers written in the above link, then I used the test written but I got the message:

```
from igraph import *    
g = Graph.Famous("petersen")
plot(g)
```

> An error is preventing the photo or video from being displayed.
>   Error code: 0x800706ba

---

I also get the following error when trying to save to a file.

```
from igraph import *    
g = Graph.Famous("petersen")
plot(g, "test.png")
```

Which gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\igraph\drawing__init__.py", line 438, in plot
>
> result.save()
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\igraph\drawing__init__.py", line 299, in save
>
> return self._surface.write_to_png(fname)
>
> IOError: error while writing to output stream

Why is this not working?

Comment: Same problem, nine months later ...

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372887/open-and-display-png-file-in-python-using-pil