# How to open a random Image from a given file directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, operating-system, windowserror

I am trying to open the image from this directory but am not been able to.
It gives me the following error:

> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect.

This is my code:

```
import os, random
random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds"+'png'))
```

In here , in the folder backgrounds there are many images.I want a random Image to open.But while running the program , I am getting `WindowsError`.

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit 1

I tried this:

```
random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds"+'png'))
```

But am getting the error:

> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect:
>   'C:\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds\*.png/*.*'

## Edit 2

I tried this:

```
import os, random

a=random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds"))
os.open(a)
```

Now I dont get error but it does not open the image either.

## Edit 3

I have also tried:

```
 import random,os
folder= "C:\\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds"
a=random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
print(a)

from PIL import Image
file = folder+'\\'+a
Image.open(file).show()

    #os.open(a, os.O_RDWR)
    from PIL import Image
    file = folder+'\\'+a
    Image.open(file).show()
```

But got the following error once again:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "G:\Grade 12
>   Project\auto.py", line 4, in 
>       a=random.choice(os.listdir(folder)) WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:
>   'C:\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca'

Here(the yellow highlighted part) is the directory where my images are stored.

[image: Image of Directory]

Comment: You have unescaped back slashes in there. Unless Python handles that differently, you'll need to add a second backslash after each existing backslash, or make them forward slashes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I gave a try on what you have said but got the error (I have edited)

Comment: The edit 2 works fine for me, are you sure that the directory structure you are given doesn't contain any typos ?

Comment: @ABcDexter does it open the image for you?

Comment: No, it didn't. But something else worked, writing that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) instead.

```
import os, random

folder=r"D:\Study\SO"

a=random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
print(a)

#os.open(a, os.O_RDWR)
from PIL import Image
file = folder+'\\'+a
Image.open(file).show()
```

source:
[Open and display .png file in python using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10372887)

---

The problem with this is that `a` doesn't have absolute path to that chosen random files.

1. In Edit 1, the "png" gets concatenated but there is no folder named "backgroundspng"
2. In Edit 2, you haven't given the flags for `os.open()` which can be [found here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm).
3. In Edit 3, please make sure that you are using the r before string.

---

In you case, use this :

```
folder = r"C:\\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds"
```

Comment: I have tried and gave my result up in the edit , please check it.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @WhiteShadow wait, you have a folder before backgrounds, right ?

Comment: You are not using right path to the folder, that is it.

Comment: Yes, I do have a folder.

Comment: But in the edit, the path you have written is incorrect.

Comment: `C:\\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\backgrounds` it should be `...ca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds` There is a folder named "0.91.6_0"

Comment: Yeah mate I did did that again and edited my answer too.But still the problem persists. Come on Indian homeboy , help me out xD. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130010/discussion-between-white-shadow-and-abcdexter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a raw string by prepending the string with `r`:

```
random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\rkp10\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\0.91.6_0\backgrounds"+'png'))
```

Else, you would need to escape each backslash by another backslash.

Comment: Hey! I am getting this error now `WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\rkp10\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\\0.91.6_0\\backgrounds\\*.png/*.*`
I dont know what's wrong? I just want it to open any random image from the directory I gave.